# System.err: TypeError: com.tns.TestObject is not a constructor

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript. I create TestObject.java in `C:\project\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns` and write this:

```
package com.tns;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
public class TestObject {
    public void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                // Not implemented
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                // Not implemented
            }
        } };

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how to call this function in main.ts in my application?

I tried ti add in TestObject.java

```
 public String doSomething () {
        return "hello";
    }
```

and in main.ts write this:

```
  var test = new com.tns.TestObject(); 
  console.log(test.doSomething());
```

error when app execute

> System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
>   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
>           System.err: Error calling module function
>           System.err: TypeError: com.tns.TestObject is not a constructor
>           System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.project/files/app/main.js, line:
>   29, column: 15
>           System.err: StackTrace:
>           System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.project/files/app/main.js',
>   line: 29, column: 16

Any idea please?

Comment: Probably your app wasnt rebuild and with that your java file would be deleted

Comment: This file exist in this folder.

Comment: have you declared the type of the main namespace  `declare let com: any;`

Comment: It can exists in folder but not in builded app, but for building app that file will be removed first

Comment: I've tested the code above and it works on my side https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/stackoverflow/javaFileUsage - of course you should add the TestJava to `platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns` as I am gitignoring the folder.

Comment: Yes @NickIliev I declare let com: any;

Comment: @MarekMaszay Builded App?

Comment: @NickIliev `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myproject\node_modules\tns-template-hello-world-ts\package.json'`

Comment: Have you added manually the `TestObject.java` in `platforms\android\app\src\main\java`

Comment: Yes, create TestObject.java in  `platforms\android\app\src\main\java` And inside this file Add `package com.tns; public class TestObject { public String doSomething () { return "hello";
    }}` `ERROR: JS: ERROR TypeError: com.tns.TestObject is not a constructor`

Comment: Excuse me the full path is as originally posted `platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns` and yep the code is working on my side (printing "hello" on load)  - the call to testObject https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/blob/master/stackoverflow/javaFileUsage/app/main-page.ts

Comment: @NickIliev please Look this post, I change code like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654664/com-tns-testobject-is-not-a-constructor/51655910#51655910 but any change